# "Unique constraint violation found" in frontend, but no trace in expection.log

Tags: database, magento2.2.9

I am pretty new to Magento and made a copy of my a production webshop for testing purposes on our server. The website looks to be working fine, but somehow I keep getting **"Unique constraint violation found"** errors in the frontend whenever I try to add a product to the cart.

The strange thing is there is no stack trace whatsoever in my exception.log

I am completely lost as to where I should even start debugging this. Does anyone have a hint for me? Can somebody help me get this error logged?

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved this myself. Googled again and realized that there is also DB-Logging, as described in the Magento Docs.

```
1. bin/magento dev:query-log:enable
2. bin/magento cache:flush
```

Enabled that and here I found the SQL Error.